# Blend material onto another material in SceneKit using PBR iOS

Tags: ios, scenekit, pbr

I have already added a material to my geometry of `SCNNode` and now I want to add another material to it and set it to blend mode 'multiply'.

I tried a lot but unable to find a way to do this. If we blend the texture as [multiply](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462575-multiply) then it works for other light setups but not with the PBR.

```
material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased

let image = UIImage(named: "1.PNG")
material.multiply.contents = image
material.multiply.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(10, 10, 0)
material.multiply.wrapT = .repeat
material.multiply.wrapS = .repeat
material.multiply.intensity = 1.0
```

Any help on this?

[image]

Thanks